# Error with Web Service reference in NetBeans 6.7.1

Tags: web-services, netbeans, servlets, reference

I have created a java web project to make a servlet. However, it used to work fine before i reinstalled it. the Web Service reference doesnt not show the operations and gives the following error:

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.<init>(DOMForest.java:153)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.resetSchema(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:204)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.<init>(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.XJC.createSchemaCompiler(XJC.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.<init>(WsimportOptions.java:100)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.generateWsdlModel(WsdlModeler.java:197)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.generateWsdlModel(WsdlModeler.java:189)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.access$000(WsdlModeler.java:73)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler$1.run(WsdlModeler.java:98)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:577)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1030)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found

You need to make sure that JAR file(s) of [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/) is in the runtime classpath.

Comment: thanx...i'l look into it. Can you please tell explain the "runtime classpath"? :S

Comment: The `WEB-INF/lib` folder is covered by the default webapp's runtime classpath. Drop any 3rd party webapp-related JAR files in there. If you have full control over the appserver and you want to share the same JAR's among all webapps on the same server, you can also drop them in the `AppserverRootFolder/lib`.